# Why isn't my session variable unsetting correctly in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, session, cookies

I'm making an authentification system with a Remember Me option. Everything works fine, except for one thing : When I don't check the Remember Me checkbox, it keeps me connected, even after restarting my navigator, or even my computer. While the cookie is unset, the session variable stays.

I've already tried a bunch of things but the session variable staying after restarting everything isn't normal.

Here's my account page code :

```
if (!session_id()) {
   session_start();
}

$secondDB = new wpdb('XXX', 'XXX', 'XXX', 'XXX');

$allCustomers = $secondDB->get_results("SELECT * FROM client");

if (!isset($_COOKIE["connectedUser"])) $_COOKIE["connectedUser"] = false;
if ($_COOKIE["connectedUser"]=='null') $_COOKIE["connectedUser"] = false;

echo "Cookie : ".$_COOKIE["connectedUser"]."<br>";
echo "Session : ".$_SESSION["connectedUserID"]."<br>";

if($_COOKIE["connectedUser"] != false && !isset($_SESSION["connectedUser"]))
{
    $_SESSION["connectedUserID"] = $_COOKIE["connectedUser"];
}

if(isset($_SESSION["connectedUserID"]))
{
    foreach($allCustomers as $customer)
    {
        if($customer->client_id == $_SESSION["connectedUserID"])
        {
            foreach($customer as $key=>$value) {
                echo "<strong>".$key." : </strong>".$value."<br>";
            }
        }
    }
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<a href=\"http://numerisat.fr/deconnexion/\">Log out</a>";
} else {
    // AUTHENTIFICATION
    echo "<form action=\"\" method=\"POST\">";
    echo "<label for=\"username\">Login :</label>";
    echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"username\" required/>";
    echo "<label for=\"password\">Password :</label>";
    echo "<input type=\"password\" name=\"password\" required/>";
    echo "<label for=\"remember\">Remember me</label>";
    echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"remember\"/>";
    echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"valider\" value=\"Log in\">";
    echo "</form>";

    $authResult = "";

    if(!empty($_POST["username"]) && !empty($_POST["password"]))
    {
        foreach($allCustomers as $customer) {
            if($customer->client_username == $_POST["username"])
            {
                if($customer->client_password == md5($_POST["password"]))
                {
                    $_SESSION["connectedUserID"] = $customer->client_id;
                    if($_POST["remember"] == "on")
                    {
                        setcookie("connectedUser", $_SESSION["connectedUserID"], time()+3600*24*15, "/");
                    }
                    header('Location: http://numerisat.fr/espace-client/');
                } else {
                    $authResult = "Invalid login or password. Please try again.";
                }
            } else {
                $authResult = "Invalid login or password. Please try again.";
            }
        }
        echo $authResult;
    }
}
```

And here's my log out code :

```
if (!session_id()) {
   session_start();
}

unset($_COOKIE["connectedUser"]);
setcookie("connectedUser", false, time()-3600, "/");
unset($_SESSION["connectedUserID"]);
session_destroy();
header("Location: http://numerisat.fr/espace-client/");
```

What I want is that the user can choose to stay connected or not when they leave their navigator. For the time being, it always keeps them connected, whether or not they want it.

Do you have any explanation on where this problem comes from ? I'm kind of lost. Thanks !

Comment: try dumping the $_SESSION variable in the logout code after you call session_destroy() to check whether its destroyed properly.

Comment: The $_SESSION variable returns array(0) { } . On the account page, I display (with echo) the cookie and the session variable, and the session variable is never removed, while the cookie is.

Comment: mm...thats wierd..are you setting the $_SESSION variable in any page other than account page?

Comment: _“Everything works fine”_ - really …? It looks like all I would need to know is the id of a user in your system, to be able to “log in” _as_ that user, by simply sending the user id as value of the cookie `connectedUser`.

Comment: No, the only code where I interact with session variables are those two code snippets. This is why I find this really strange.

Comment: For the time being, I'm using a simple authentification system for the basics. Later, I'll enhance security, features and data access. Now, my primary problem is this session thing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK ! I think I found the source of my problem. I feel kind of dumb, but let me explain, and tell whoever has a similar problem.

Even after updating WordPress to a recent version tu upgrade to PHP 7.1 and be able to use WP Session Manager plugin, sessions weren't working.

After looking for way too long for an answer, changing my code to find a way, I finally realized something.

Firefox. In the settings, I checked the "Restore previous session" box. So everytime I left Firefox and went back to it, it would restore all of my information.

**Uncheck the "Restore previous session" box, and it should work.**

That was where my problems came from.

Thanks anyway for your help !